# d3 line chart not displayed properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have problem with my line chart. It creates line from first point to last one which destroy my chart data.
data:

```
$scope.data = _data = [{
                "label": 1,
                "value": 20
                },
            {
                "label": 2,
                "value": 50
                },
            {
                "label": 3,
                "value": 30
                }];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8fue95u3/5/

Why it is displayed and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [D3 line acting as a closed path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684690/d3-line-acting-as-a-closed-path) it seems like you'll need to set your path fill to 'none'

```
svg.append("path")
    ...
    .style("fill", "none")
```